# RoadtripView.put() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

Tags: python

I will try to explain my problem in English, because in fact I speak rather French.
I have a little problem and it's been 5 hours now that I can't solve it. I wrote three functions GET, POST and PUT. the first two work well but the PUT has a problem. I am looking to update my Roadtrip table. I send you my codes

```
# Research for Roadtrip class RoadtripView(CRUDView):
    queryset = Roadtrip.objects.all().order_by("-id")
    serializer_class=RoadtripSerializers
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['cfrom','gto','date']

    # Get
    def get(self,request,id=None):
        if id:
            return self.retrieve(request)
        else:
            return self.list(request)
    # Post
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        RoadtripSerializers.Meta.depth = 0
        data = request.data
        wrappers = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        RoadtripSerializers.Meta.depth = 1
        return wrappers

    # Update
    def put(self,request,id,pk,*args,**kwargs):
        kwargs['pk'] = self.request.id
        RoadtripSerializers.Meta.depth = 0
        user = request.user
        if user != None:
            data = request.data
            roadid = Roadtrip.objects.get(id=pk)
            submit = super().update(request, pk, *args, **kwargs)
            return submits
```

My Model:

```
class Roadtrip(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    cfrom = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True,)
    gto = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True,)
    date= models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    frontsits = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,)
    backsits = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True,)
    hour = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True,)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"coming_from=={self.cfrom}<==>going_to:{self.gto}==Date=={self.date}==Hour=={self.hour}"
```

My URL

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(route.urls)),
    path("roadtrip/",RoadtripView.as_view(),name="roadtrip"),
    path("roadtrip/<int:id>/",RoadtripView.as_view(),name="roadtripdetal"),
    path("booking/<int:id>",BookingView.as_view(),name="booking"),
    path("booking/",BookingView.as_view(),name="booking"),
    # path("contact/",ContactView.as_view(),name="contact"),
    # path("contact/<int:id>",ContactView.as_view(),name="contact"),
    path("payment/",PaymentView.as_view(),name="payment"),
    path("addtobooking/",addtobooking.as_view(),name="addtobooking"),
]
```

Error on Swagger doc :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV1Vi.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to add your code.

Comment: You are missing the `class ...` line in your first code snippet.

Comment: You should use `id` or `pk` in the argument list for `put()`, but not both. I suggest using `pk` because there is a global `id()` function that you will hide if you use the variable name `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
    def put(self,request,id,pk,*args,**kwargs):
```

to

```
    def put(self,request,id,*args,**kwargs): # remove pk
```

I also suggest that you change `id` to `pk` everywhere.